# How to create record on cascade tables with linq in mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, crud

I'm working on a mvc web-app for creating DeskAlerts. I have this configurations in my DB :

```
AlertMap
AlertMapID (pk)
AlertID (fk)
UsersID (fk)
AlertModeID (fk)
AlertPriorityID (fk)

AlertPrioriy (1-* to AlertMap)
AlertPriorityID (pk)
AlertPriorityCde
AlertPriorityLabel

AlertMode (1-* to AlertMap)
AlertModeID (pk)
AlertModeCde
AlertModeLabel

AlertLog (1-* to AlertMap)
AlertID (pk),AlertTitle,AlertText,AlertStartDate,AlertEndDate,AlertActive

AspNetUsers (1-* to AlertMap)
Id (pk),UserName
```

So AlertMap is for mapping my data. Reading operation works, but I don't understand how to built a cascade create operation on `AlertMap` and `AlertLog` table.

Someone told me about transaction, but I think my syntax is not correct. With this code I have no error, but nothing changes in my DB.

AlertMapsController.cs

```
public ActionResult Create(AlertMap alertMap) 
{
    ViewBag.AlertModeID = new SelectList(db.AlertMode,"AlertModeID","AlertModeID",alertMap.AlertModeID);
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
        {  
            try
            {
                var alertlog = new AlertLog();
                var alertmap = new AlertMap();

                alertlog.AlertTitle = alertMap.AlertLog.AlertTitle;
                alertlog.AlertText = alertMap.AlertLog.AlertText ;
                alertlog.AlertStartDate = alertMap.AlertLog.AlertStartDate;
                alertlog.AlertEndDate = alertMap.AlertLog.AlertEndDate;
                alertlog.AlertActive = alertMap.AlertLog.AlertActive ;
                db.AlertLog.add(alertlog);
                db.SaveChanges();

                var userid = "xyz";
                alertmap.UsersID = userid;
                alertmap.AlertModeID = ViewBag.AlertModeID;
                alertmap.AlertPriorityID = ViewBag.AlertPriorityID;
                db.AlertLog.Add(alertlog);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ts.Complete();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }
    return View(alertMap);
}
```

AlertMap.cs

```
public partial class AlertMap
{
    public int AlertMapID {get;set;}
    public int AlertID {get;set;}
    public string UsersID {get;set;}
    public int AlertModeID {get;set;}
    public int AlertPriorityID{get;set;}

    public virtual AlertLog AlertLog {get;set;}
    public virtual AlertMode AlertMode {get;set;}
    public virtual AlertPriority AlertPriority {get;set;}
    public virtual AspNetUsers AspNetUsers{get;set;}
}
```

So could you help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the syntax you used in your code but you have duplicated updating the AlertLog and you are not updating the AlertMap

```
       `var userid = "xyz";
        alertmap.UsersID = userid;
        alertmap.AlertModeID = ViewBag.AlertModeID;
        alertmap.AlertPriorityID = ViewBag.AlertPriorityID;
        db.AlertLog.Add(alertlog);
        db.SaveChanges();
        ts.Complete();`
```

If you look where you add to your DB you say 'db.AlertLog.Add(alertlog);' again when you are actually wanting to add the alertmap.

Comment: Sorry, the correct syntax in my code is : db.AlertMap.Add(alertmap); This PC is only for net (no usb key, no visual studo...). I need to copy/paste my code keyboard to keyboard from another pc. I've made a mistake.

Comment: I figured it was probably something like that, but figured I should point it out just in case. We all can make silly logic errors sometimes. I mostly handle cascading client side using MVC wrappers and their functionality, but I'll try and build a test case like yours if someone else doesn't answer this before me since that approach will not work here it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Couple issues with your code, first of all you , try to use a different name for your local variable alertmap and alertlog to differentiate it between the model name and the variable name.
I made some edits to your code as well , but i highly recommend doing some research on IoC in the future. to redesign your code/models

```
 public ActionResult Create(AlertMap alertMap) 

        {
            ViewBag.AlertModeID = new SelectList(db.AlertMode,"AlertModeID","AlertModeID",alertMap.AlertModeID);
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
                {  
                    try
                    {
                        var AlertLog = new AlertLog();
                        var AlertMap = new AlertMap();
                         //First transaction

                        AlertLog.AlertTitle = alertMap.AlertLog.AlertTitle;
                        AlertLog.AlertText = alertMap.AlertLog.AlertText ;
                        AlertLog.AlertStartDate = alertMap.AlertLog.AlertStartDate;
                        AlertLog.AlertEndDate = alertMap.AlertLog.AlertEndDate;
                        AlertLog.AlertActive = alertMap.AlertLog.AlertActive ;
                        db.AlertLog.add(AlertLog);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                         //Second transaction
                        var userid = "xyz";
                        AlertMap.UsersID = userid;
                        AlertMap.AlertModeID = ViewBag.AlertModeID;
                        AlertMap.AlertPriorityID = ViewBag.AlertPriorityID;
                        db.alertmap.Add(AlertMap);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        // If execution reaches here, it indicates the successfull completion of all two save operation. hence commit the transaction.
                        ts.Complete();
                     }


          catch (Exception ex)
                     {
                     // If any excption is caught, roll back the entire transaction and ends transaction scope
                     ts.Dispose();
                     }
                  }
               }
               return View(alertMap);
            }
```

Comment: No... I have no error when I click on create button, but nothing change on the screen, and my db don't update.

Comment: I put a breakpoint and it's seems that db.SaveChanges() has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found a solution... this is not a very clean solution, but it's works(it's not a final code). I don't use context for the moment, a friend of mine, could help me to correct my code. Thanks for help !

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AlertModeID,AlertPriorityID")] AlertMap alertMap, [Bind(Include = "AlertTitle,AlertText,AlertStartDate,AlertEndDate,AlertActive")] AlertLog alertLog)
        {
            ViewBag.AlertModeID = new SelectList(db.AlertMode, "AlertModeID", "AlertModeID", alertMap.AlertModeID);
            ViewBag.AlertPriorityID = new SelectList(db.AlertPriority, "AlertPriorityID", "AlertPriorityID", alertMap.AlertPriorityID);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int alertid = (from p in db.AlertLog select p.AlertID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (alertid == 0)
                    alertid++;
                else
                    alertid = (from r in db.AlertLog select r.AlertID).Max() + 1;

                int mapid = (from s in db.AlertMap select s.AlertMapID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (mapid == 0)
                    mapid++;
                else
                    mapid = (from t in db.AlertMap select t.AlertMapID).Max() + 1;

                        alertLog.AlertID = alertid;
                        db.AlertLog.Add(alertLog);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        int falertid = (from r in db.AlertLog select r.AlertID).Max();
                        alertMap.AlertMapID = mapid;
                        alertMap.AlertID = falertid;
                        alertMap.UsersID = "45d4778b-2b28-45f5-a6e4-5b0b2d3e8f8c";
                        db.AlertMap.Add(alertMap);
                        db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View(alertMap);
        }
```